# Rewrite URL to Exclude File Extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'd like to rewrite my URLs to exclude the file extension. For example:

```
http://www.example.com/filename.php
```

should become:

```
http://www.example.com/filename/
```

or:

```
http://www.example.com/filename
```

(both should be accepted)

This makes for a cleaner URL. How can I rewrite URLs this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If folder does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# and file exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
# uncomment the below rule if you want / not optional 
# otherwise leave as is
# RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]
# internally show the content of filename.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

This might be pretty much what you need.

Comment: Why does including the trailing slash break my CSS reference? Specifically, this: `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: can you try giving full URL instead of relative url.